# GOOGLEFINANCE: Finding a defined price for a stock at a certain date (whenever that defined price was reached) and returning it to a cell

Tags: google-finance-api

Thanks for reading this - I'm a beginner with google sheets and hope you can help me finding a solution to my little problem! Here it comes: I want to extract the (historic) date from GOOGLEFINANCE when a stock price has hit a certain price. Example: Say I know a share was worth $ 10 on December 15, 2008 and it hit a low of $ 5 on March 20, 2009. I want to know how long it took that stock before it came back to $ 10 and would like to get the output (date) in a defined cell. Is there a function or combination of functions I can use? (Besides a few macro editings I have no experience in scripting/programming with google sheets...). Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks much in advance! RJ

Comment: Read the docs at: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Dougie, I did. It is helpful to capture the Shareprices, but I strougle with the progrmming logic (code) to find the date when the shareprice exceeds the December 15 2008 hight again. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks in advance! RJ